# Write the expression in terms of $\log{a}$ and $\log{b}$

Tags: calculus

Write in terms of $\log{a}$ and $\log{b}$ : $\log{\frac{a^3}{b^4}}$?

using log laws $log(\frac{x}{y})$ = $\log{x} - \log{y}$

$\log{\frac{a^3}{b^4}} = \log{a^3} - \log{b^4}$

and using log law that $\log{x^y} = y\log{x}$

$\log{a^3} = 3 \log{a}$ & $\log{b^4} = 4\log{b}$

therefore $\log{\frac{a^3}{b^4}} = 3\log{a} - 4\log{b}$

does that seem correct? please show your solution.

Comment: Write in terms of loga and logb : (log)((a^3/(b^4))?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes.  This looks like homework, but work is shown as we ask.  Yes, the comment is extraneous, but we see much worse.

Answer (score 2):

It seems correct, you used well the logarithm laws.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I don't think you have enough reputation, but this is better as a comment. Regards